# Selenium IDE and Select2 drop down interactions

Tags: jquery, html, selenium, selenium-ide, jquery-select2

I'm trying to write a test-script for Selenium IDE on a website using Select2. I can get as far as clicking the drop down menu from Select2. That step passes according to the Selenium console, yet nothing actually happens with the element. I've tried using the click command, as well as the select command, with varying selectors from CSS to nearly every point of the XPath value.

I need to know the proper commands and how to execute them to make Selenium interact with Select2 as if it were a real user. After opening the drop down list, I need some command to select a specific option on that list. Example code:

```
<div id="select2-drop-mask" class="select2-drop-mask" style="display: block;"/>
<div id="select2-drop" class="select2-drop select2-display-none select2-drop-active select2-drop-above" style="left: 1015.5px; width: 438px; top: auto; bottom: -229px; display: block;">
<div class="select2-search select2-search-hidden select2-offscreen">
<span class="fa fa-search select2-search-placeholder"/>
<input class="select2-input" type="text" placeholder="Search" spellcheck="false" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" autocomplete="off"/>
</div>
<ul class="select2-results">
<li class="select2-results-dept-0 select2-result select2-result-selectable select2-highlighted">
<div class="select2-result-label">
</li>
<li class="select2-results-dept-0 select2-result select2-result-selectable">
<div class="select2-result-label">
<span class="select2-match"/>
Fraudulent Account (ID Theft)
</div>
</li>
```

What selectors and commands do I need to use in Selenium IDE, to properly interact with Select2 elements like drop downs?

Comment: You've expressed a need, but what, specifically, is the question? For help, see “[How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)”.

Comment: Right, forgot to ask the question. Ammending now.